# How can I take the days of months with switch function?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am writing a C program to get the number of days in a month just entering the number of month. I want my code to show the asked month while printing. I mean, if the user enters 5: `May has 31 days.` But in my code, it gives: `5 has 31 days.` How can I correct it so it takes the cases from code above?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
        int month, year;
        int i;
        int thirty_days[] = {4, 6, 9, 11};
        int thirty_one_days[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12};

        printf("Enter a number between 1 and 12: ");
        scanf("%i", &month);
        while(month>12 || month<0){
                printf("Between 1 and 12! Try again: ");
                scanf("%i", &month);
        }

        for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
                if (month == thirty_days[i]) {
                        printf("%i has 30 days!", month);
                        break;}
                else if (month == thirty_one_days[i]) {
                        printf("%i has 31 days!", month);
                        break;}
        }
        char* getMonthName(int number_of_month){

        char* month;
        switch (number_of_month) {
                case 0:
                        month = "January";
                        break;
                case 1:
                        month = "February";
                        break;
                case 2:
                        month = "March";
                        break;
                case 3:
                        month = "April";
                        break;
                case 4:
                        month = "May";
                        break;
                case 5:
                        month = "June";
                        break;
                case 6:
                        month = "July";
                        break;
                case 7:
                        month = "August";
                        break;
                case 8:
                        month = "September";
                        break;
                case 9:
                        month = "October";
                        break;
                case 10:
                        month = "November";
                        break;
                case 11:
                        month = "December";
                        break;
        }
        return month;
        }

        if (month == 2) {
                printf("Enter the year: ");
                scanf("%i", &year);
                if (year % 400 == 0 || (year %4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)){
                                printf("February has 29 days in this leap year!");}
                else {
                        printf("February has 28 days in this year!");}
        }
}
```

I am not a native English, pardon me if I made mistakes while explaining.

Comment: Compile your C code with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable. Be aware that [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) can fail.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry, I didn't quite understand. I am new to C programming. Do I have to write my file's name while compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ? Because it says `fatal error: no input files`

Comment: Yes, you do need to read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), and reading it will take you several hours. You also should read the documentation of GDB and look into [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: What is the value of `thirty_days[i]` when `i` reaches the value `4`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the number, use the number as an argument for `getMonthName()` like follows and then print the returned string:

```
    char *name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (month == thirty_days[i])
        {
            name = getMonthName(month - 1);
            printf("%s has 30 days!", name);
            break;
        }
        else if (month == thirty_one_days[i])
        {
            name = getMonthName(month - 1);
            printf("%s has 31 days!", name);
            break;
        }
    }
```

The above code produces the required output! :)

**EDIT: Your positioning of functions in the code is incorrect, here is the right version:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getMonthName(int number_of_month)
{

    char *month;
    switch (number_of_month)
    {
    case 0:
        month = "January";
        break;
    case 1:
        month = "February";
        break;
    case 2:
        month = "March";
        break;
    case 3:
        month = "April";
        break;
    case 4:
        month = "May";
        break;
    case 5:
        month = "June";
        break;
    case 6:
        month = "July";
        break;
    case 7:
        month = "August";
        break;
    case 8:
        month = "September";
        break;
    case 9:
        month = "October";
        break;
    case 10:
        month = "November";
        break;
    case 11:
        month = "December";
        break;
    }
    return month;
}

int main()
{
    int month, year;
    int i;
    int thirty_days[] = {4, 6, 9, 11};
    int thirty_one_days[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12};

    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 12: ");
    scanf("%i", &month);
    while (month > 12 || month < 0)
    {
        printf("Between 1 and 12! Try again: ");
        scanf("%i", &month);
    }

    char *name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (month == thirty_days[i])
        {
            name = getMonthName(month - 1);
            printf("%s has 30 days!", name);
            break;
        }
        else if (month == thirty_one_days[i])
        {
            name = getMonthName(month - 1);
            printf("%s has 31 days!", name);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (month == 2)
    {
        printf("Enter the year: ");
        scanf("%i", &year);
        if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
        {
            printf("February has 29 days in this leap year!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("February has 28 days in this year!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `malloc`?

Comment: `malloc` is used to allocate memory for a pointer. Do check out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/

Comment: Sorry, If you misunderstood, my question was not "What is the purpose of `malloc`". But rather "What is the purpose of *the* `malloc` in your code". You are allocating memory, just to lose track of it. And, no, `malloc` is not used to allocate memory for a pointer, but allocating memory that a pointer may point at. There is a subtle distinction. Typically we are lazy and say the former when we mean the latter, but there is a lot of misunderstandings about `malloc`, so I just wanted to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

Use one array to hold the no of days for each month and move getMonthName outside main.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* getMonthName(int number_of_month){

        char* month;
        switch (number_of_month) {
                case 0:
                        month = "January";
                        break;
                case 1:
                        month = "February";
                        break;
                case 2:
                        month = "March";
                        break;
                case 3:
                        month = "April";
                        break;
                case 4:
                        month = "May";
                        break;
                case 5:
                        month = "June";
                        break;
                case 6:
                        month = "July";
                        break;
                case 7:
                        month = "August";
                        break;
                case 8:
                        month = "September";
                        break;
                case 9:
                        month = "October";
                        break;
                case 10:
                        month = "November";
                        break;
                case 11:
                        month = "December";
                        break;
        }
        return month;
        }

int main () {
        int month, year;
        int i;
        int days[]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        
        printf("Enter a number between 1 and 12: ");
        scanf("%i", &month);
        while(month>12 || month<0){
                printf("Between 1 and 12! Try again: ");
                scanf("%i", &month);
        }

        if (month == 2) {
                printf("Enter the year: ");
                scanf("%i", &year);
                if (year % 400 == 0 || (year %4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)){
                                printf("February has 29 days in this leap year!");}
                else {
                        printf("February has 28 days in this year!");}
        } else {
            printf("%s has %i days!", getMonthName(month-1), days[month-1]);   
        }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf` otherwise you will have a nice infinite loop on wrong input, EOF or IO-Error